# Hide/unhide navigation buttons

Tags: angularjs

In my AngularJS application I am using a panel that is divided into the header, the body and the footer. The start page contains a few buttons that lead to subsequent pages. In the footer I would like to have a "back button" on the left side and a "next button" on the right side that lead to the next/previous page. How can I achive that the buttons are only displayed where they make sense? Example: Buttons are not shown on the start page, a selection is made and a differnt page is loaded, the "back button" should be displayed in the footer. "Back button" is clicked, application goes back to the previous page (the main screen) and the "back button" is hidden.

[image: app]

Comment: that sounds good....I think you missed the code here

Comment: Put the footer in each page, since it's different in each page. Other solutions might exist, but they depend on your code, which matters.

Comment: Have you tried coding it?  If so, can we see the code?